# Django multiple-choice field of options in database

Tags: python, django, database-design, model

I am designing a model, view and template for my news aggregation app. I want the template to offer the user a multiple-choice field form with options from the database. How do I design this in my model?

I was reading the Django documentation about ManyToManyField (the one with journalists and articles) but I don't think that is quite the right relationship because in my case, "articles" can exist without a journalist and journalist without an article.

I have Users. I have Streams. Streams is a collection of news sites a user can sign up to follow and see aggregated headline snippets, such as from CNN,Twitter, Google News, etc etc. A Stream can exist with no Users. A Stream can have many Users. A User can have no Streams, in fact all user accounts start in my app with no Streams until they choose one. A User can have many Streams.

In the template, I want to create a form with the list of all the Stream options in the database (this will likely change as I ad more options in the future). When a User selects a Stream, it will be added to their dashboard view. They can add and delete Streams. However, there is only 1 Twitter, 1 Google News, etc source. I can't use the typical choices option in the User model, I want it to be "dynamic" and pull straight from the Streams database.

This is what I have now but I know it's not right:

**streams/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Stream(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**user/models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

     '''''
     #TODO: make this dynamic, streams is pulling from Streams model
        streams = (
            ('Google News'),
            ('Yahoo News'),
            ('Twitter'),
            ('CNN'),
            ('New York Times'),
            ('NBC News'),
            ('Huffington Post')
        )
        stream_choices = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=streams)


     '''''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one model for list of streams and another model for user selected streams

```
class Stream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserStream(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Stream)
```

That's it. Insert possible streams to `Stream` model and user selected streams to `UserStream` model.

Comment: Ah! I see, an intermediary table! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ManyToManyField` already implicitly creates the 'intermediary table' described in the accepted answer. As per the documentation:

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to
>   represent the many-to-many relationship.

You can pass a callable to the `choices` field of the `ChoicesField` which you display to the user, allowing the list of available choices to be determined dynamically when the form is generated.

The list of valid choices in the User<->Stream relationship is already constrained by the relationship, so there's no benefit in specifying the available choices on the model field.